# How convert entire hex file to bin?

Tags: python, hex, bin

I'm hoping to make use of [`intelhex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IntelHex/2.0), but am not fully understanding what it needs to be passed to simply convert an entire file.

In `test-usage.py`:

```
import os
import sys
from intelhex import hex2bin

with open("foo.hex", "r") as fin:
    start = 0
    end = 218
    size = None
    pad = None
    print("start: {}\nend: {}\nsize: {}\npad: {}".format(start, end, size, pad))
    hex2bin(fin, sys.stdout, start, end, size, pad)
```

Error:

```
start: 0
end: 218
size: None
pad: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-usage.py", line 19, in <module>
    hex2bin(fin, sys.stdout, start, end, size, pad)
  File "/home/me/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/intelhex/__init__.py", line 1001, in hex2bin
    h.tobinfile(fout, start, end)
  File "/home/me/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/intelhex/__init__.py", line 412, in tobinfile
    fobj.write(self._tobinstr_really(start, end, pad, size))
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

`foo.hex` borrowed from [here](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/1584/):

```
:10001300AC12AD13AE10AF1112002F8E0E8F0F2244
:10000300E50B250DF509E50A350CF5081200132259
:03000000020023D8
:0C002300787FE4F6D8FD7581130200031D
:10002F00EFF88DF0A4FFEDC5F0CEA42EFEEC88F016
:04003F00A42EFE22CB
:00000001FF
```

http://python-intelhex.readthedocs.org/en/latest/part3-1.html

[Usage of hex2bin in the example script source](https://github.com/bialix/intelhex/blob/master/scripts/hex2bin.py).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please define both formats and give example data.

Answer (score 0):

Support doesn't seem quite yet there for python3.  Creating a new virtual environment with python2 (a little outside the scope of this question), I'm able to execute without error.

```
ENV_NAME=testenv
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2 ${ENV_NAME}
source ${ENV_NAME}/bin/activate
pip install IntelHex==2.0
./test-usage.py

start: 0
end: 218
size: None
pad: None
#�
�  %
5
 "����/"x����u����������Τ.�����.�"��������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������
```

I should also note that to simply convert the entire file, you should leave all non-file parameters as default.  For example:

```
hex2bin(fin, sys.stdout)
```